# How check the availably of all objective-c function in source code for Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, backwards-compatibility

When you read the `Class Reference` of every object of iOS, you will find:

`Available in iOS 2.0 and later.`

There are a program or a way to list all function and the minimum iOS system?

How can I know if the  iPhone with iOS 3.0 will run all iOS function? I can check it in runtime with `respondToSelector`, but can be more easy with source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your project's base SDK to iOS 3, and see if it builds.

Comment: Wow, great idea! Why I not think it>>

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to list all the APIs you use in your app into one list and check that you are building past the minimum for all those APIs. You will just have to check each one, one by one. Highlight the API in Xcode, and then click escape and it will tell you very easily.
But also I have to mention that this won't be extremely necessary since you should test on the minimum OS you are building for and if it crashes at any point then you have your issue for that certain API.

Comment: One by one if very difficult :( And if I do not have a device to test? Lol, use the simulator, but.. This is not a easy way

Comment: You should always have a device to test on before you submit an app to the store. I know it is not easy but once you test on a device you will see if there are issues are not, you don't have to look up each API you use one-by-one.